# How do I fix a wireless connection in lubuntu?

Tags: wireless, 13.04, lubuntu

I recently installed Lubuntu in a dual-boot setup on my Lenovo Thinkpad X131E. Everything works fine, except that wifi is extremely slow. I am unable to get a good connection even from a few feet away. I have had problems with the laptop forcing IPv6 on Windows 8 and Lubuntu, and had to disable IPv6 to fix it for both. The wireless works well in Windows 8, but is very slow in Lubuntu, so I know it is a problem with Lubuntu. I cannot install the recommended proprietary driver because it does not work on the device (I have tried). Can anyone help me? Thanks.

When I type `lpsci -nnk | grep -A2 0280` the output is

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:0608]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

Comment: You should give us some hardware and drivers info. For starters, what's the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280`?

Comment: I added the output to the question.